# Scala 2.12.4: Cannot access protected static Java method from another package anymore

Tags: scala

I have java class with protected static method:

```
package parent;

public class Parent {

    protected static void parentMethod() {
        System.out.println("I'm in parent static method");
    }

}
```

Before Scala 2.12.4  (2.12.3) I could call this method from another package like this:

```
package child

import parent.Parent

class Child extends Parent {

  def childMethod = {
    println("I'm in child method and calling parentMethod")
    Parent.parentMethod()
  }

}
```

But Scala 2.12.4 does not compile this code. I'm getting the error:

> Error:(9, 12) method parentMethod in object Parent cannot be accessed
>   in object parent.Parent  Access to protected method parentMethod not
>   permitted because  prefix type parent.Parent.type does not conform to 
>   object Child in package child where the access takes place
>       Parent.parentMethod()

This access pattern was very important for me because JOOQ code generation uses this.

What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice catch, this is most likely a regression introduced by [this PR](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6058/files), as part of a solution to [this issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6934).

I've already opened [a ticket](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10697) for this that you can track. In the meanwhile, if this kind of access pattern is vital for your application, unfortunately I don't think you have much choice but to stick to Scala 2.12.3 for the time being.

#### Edit

The issue was already known and [a fix has been already merged](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6260). As of the time of writing the patch is bound to be part of the 2.12.5 release.

Comment: The SLS for the `protected` keyword (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#protected) seem to point in the direction of this being a regression, thus I'm fairly sure the Scala team will pick this up and solve it. But, as I mentioned, for the time being you may want to stick to 2.12.3 if this breaks your code.

Comment: See the edit. Apparently you'll just have to skip 2.12.4.